# printf("\% %d", ...) is not working as expected

Tags: c, printf

```
printf("%d \% %d = %d", 4, 3, 1);
```

I was expecting this to print "4 % 3 = 1", but instead it prints "4 %d = 3". How can I make this print the expected result? Does "\" not disable the "%" following it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%%` is the pattern to escape a `%`, so write `printf("%d %% %d = %d")`